Validation Problem For Request Class in Spring
In the application, I have an entity class named "Car" and a request class named "AddCarRequest" from which I will get information about that class via user input.
@RequestMapping("/saveAddCarForm")
    public String saveCarForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("addCarRequest") AddCarRequest addCarRequest , BindingResult bindingResult) {


        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-car-form" ;
        }
        else {
            carService.addCar(addCarRequest);
        }

        return "redirect:/" ;
    }


When I validate with valid in my controller like this, it does not validate on the addCarRequest object, it uses the annotations in the car class. After doing some research, I saw that the source of this problem could be that I map my addCarRequest object to a car object in my service method and save my car object to the db. However, I need to do it like this. Have you ever encountered a problem like this? If you want to see extra classes ı can share
I tried lots of thing but ı couldnt solve

does your controller have @Validated annotation on class level? Do you have the validation dependency?

Yes , ı have both of them . I have no doubt with working of validation . My problem is validation is not working truely . ı am trying to validate addCarRequest class but it is working for Car class . So ı can not catch validation errors on the addCarRequest with binding result

I solved myh problem . It was about validation annotations

Unless you explain how you solved the problem, this answer is not helpful to anyone.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
